# Installing IBConsole on client PC

Tags: installation, interbase

Does anyone know if it's possible to install IBConsole on a client PC and then connect to the server (in LAN)?

I installed Interbase 2020 on my server together with IBConsole; all working fine.

I have been searching everywhere how to install IBConsole on my desktop but cannot seem to find anything. A "Client Only" installation of Interbase didn't install it either.

Is it possible/allowed to do this and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; it is possible to install InterBase client binaries on a separate machine. Your choice of "Client Only" in the installer is the correct one.

I see the installer is asking for some extraneous information (server TCP port, instance name etc.) that are not required (or relevant) for a "Client Only" install. Give some unused port number, and instance name, and provide a target folder for your client binaries. Once the install has completed, you should see the file, Install.log, in that folder. Check if IBConsole.exe is listed there, and if gds32.dll/ibclient64.dll (InterBase client library) are listed there as well as installed.

For my testing, I installed the client on a folder outside of "Program Files" successfully. I did not try installing the client under "Program Files".